# Registering a dll returns 0x80020009 error

Tags: dll, windows-7

I am trying to register with regsvr32.exe the prnadmin.dll (on a Win7 target machine) but i get this error `0x80020009`

Any suggestions please?

Comment: Are you running the command as an administrator?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

regsvr32.exe needs to be run as an administrator.  Maybe this was the cause?

Answer (score 2):

For Windows Vista/Windows 7 users:
Click Start>All Programs>Accessories, then right-click on “Command Prompt” and select “Run as Administrator”
Type in the following command exactly as you see it and press ENTER.
secedit /configure /cfg %windir%\inf\defltbase.inf /db defltbase.sdb /verbose
Wait for the command to complete, it can take some time so please be patient.
Once the command has completed, try to register a dll file again.

Comment: I recommend this answer be enhanced to explain exactly what that command does. Asking people to copy and paste arbitrary commands which clearly affect security in some way is not a good idea without explanation and references.

Answer (score 2):

For Windows Vista/Windows 7 users: Click *Start* > *All Programs* > *Accessories*, then right-click on *Command Prompt* and select *Run as Administrator*.

Answer (score 1):

Best method I have found is to open the PowerShell ise with administration rights then *cd* to `c:\` and insert your command, for example

```
regsvr32 "c:\Program Files\Windows Media Player\wmpband.dll"
```

Answer (score 0):

For Windows Vista/Windows 7 users: Click Start > All Programs > Accessories, then right-click on Command Prompt and select Run as Administrator.
Then type: regsvr32 filelocation\fileName
Then you see that file which generate error is loadded successfully.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with our Office COM addin. Visual Studio 2019 could successfully build the C++ code, but the registration failed with the above error code.

Solution was: Some files had a "wrong" file encoding (UTF8-BOM) instead of (UTF8) and after I changed the file encodings everything worked as expected.

Answer (score -3):

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2466246

You'll need to use the 32bit version of regsvr32 as mentioned in the article.

Comment: link to incorrect kb article: 
Printer VBScript error: 0x1A8. Object required