# Issue on Dll Register after migrating the project from **VS 2012** to **VS2013**

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, dll, visual-studio-2013, migration

I`m having a Issue on Dll Register after  migrating the project from **VS 2012** to **VS2013**

Actually Im working on a custom project, were we qualify our application on each visual studio version, previously we did a migration for **VS 2010** to **VS 2012**, during which there was no issues with any components but now when Migrating from **VS 2012** to **VS 2013**, we are facing  a issue while registering a `dll`.

I don't see any major differences in the current migration process when compared with that of the previous migration activity what we have carried out so far.

**Error Message:**

We are getting The module `"XXX.dll"` was loaded but the call to `DllRegisterServer` failed with error code `0x80020009`.

We are using Windows7, 64 bit machine and the project is built on 64 bit project setting. The command prompt to register the dll is executed in administration mode.

**What we have Tried so far:**

- I have referred this SO ,[Registering a dll returns 0x80020009 error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2727563/registering-a-dll-returns-0x80020009-error) for the error code what we are getting on DLL register process, but it did'nt resolve the issue
- Tried this solution as well http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?722793-RESOLVED-call-to-DLLRegisterServer-failed-error-code-0x80020009 , but no use

Any help on this will be much appreciated.

Comment: Have you looked at the dll using dependency viewer?

Comment: Are you statically or dynamically linking the C++ runtime library?

Comment: @Bathsheba: yes already checkeed in dependcy walker and all the dependents are built in 64 bit properly.

Comment: Presumably you've debugged the dll using regsvr as the starting executable?

Comment: @Bathsheba: Thanks for your valuable time and suggestions but the issue was with a 3rd party library called 'Smart Heap' which is not supported on VS 2013 . i`ll close this Question with respective answer when SO allows to do so

Comment: I'm glad you found the answer; which is worth upvoting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally after struggling so much with this issue, i was able to solve this problem .

The main issue was with a 3rd party Library called `Smart Heap`, which is not supported/compatible  with VS 2013 and hence it impacted the DLL registration of the other DLL's.

I was able to identify the Root Cause , by excluding all the 3rd party libraries and building the solution seperately, which resulted in a successful registration of the respective DLL's smoothly without any glitches.

Special Thanks to [Bathsheba](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2380830/bathsheba), who helped me in thinking in a way i was able to isolate the problem by excluding every 3rd party component separately and verifying the problem.

Thanks [Bathsheba](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2380830/bathsheba)